# How could i install JSF in ubuntu?

Tags: apache2, tomcat, jboss, glassfish

How could I add JSF to my system having JEE, tomcat, jboss, glassfish, and apache working?

Comment: What version of Java do you need?

Comment: version 7 update 4

Comment: The first step would probably be to find an answer here that describes installing java7, and make sure you don't have problems with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be helpful for you....
[JSF INSTALL PROCEDURE](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=901442)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: ok i am sorry...Actually i am new in this community so i have no idea ..how to make effective posts here...sorryyyy again..@jrg

Comment: This procedure is too old there is no package called Mojara.jar nowadays and procedure doestn't work on ubuntu 12.04 . Ive tried before i asked my question here